# If I create UIPageViewController Application in iOS 5 then will it run on iPhone 3G and iPhone 4G?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Basically I need to create some fancy page turn effect in my iPad application. I loaded .pdf file in my application now my next task is to create page turn effect. I already used and checked many sample code. I need some different look.

Now my question is, if I implement IPPageViewController in iPad using iOS 5 then will it work for iOS 3 and iOS 4 lower version?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

UIPageViewController Class Reference

> > Inherits from 
> >     UIViewController : UIResponder : NSObject
> >     Conforms to
> >     NSCoding (UIViewController)
> >     UIAppearanceContainer (UIViewController)
> >     NSObject (NSObject)
> >     Framework 
> >     /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework
> >     Availability
> >     *Available in iOS 5.0 and later.*
> >     Declared in
> >     UIPageViewController.h

So no.  It's only available in iOS 5.

Comment: Thanks friend giving me brief description.

Comment: No problem.  If you absolutely must support lower OS versions, might I recommend the leaves project.  It's quite famous on github and app-store safe.

Comment: How i increase size of pdf page from your given example?